# Does Python IDE have a module which imports math functions such as cos or sin?

Tags: python, math, import

Currently, I'm working on a program which takes some user input and uses this information to work out a question e.g cos50 or anything like that. I'm not entirely sure if python has a module which allows these sorts of equations however so I was wondering if anyone knows about one. An example of my coding can be found below:

```
# SINE AND COSINE CALCULATOR #
loop = True
while loop == True:
    UserInput = input("Would you like to work out Sine or Cosine rule?")
    UserInputCaps = UserInput.upper()
    if "COSINE" in UserInputCaps:
        D = input("Enter the value of the paired angle:")
        a = float(input("Enter the value of length A"))
        b = float(input("Enter the value of length B"))
        c = (a**2) + (b**2) - (2*a*b)* cos(D)
        print(c)
    if "SINE" in UserInputCaps:
        a = input("Please enter the length")
        A = input("Please enter the angle")
        b = input("Please enter the other angle")
        ans = (a / sin(A)) * sin(b)
        print(ans)
```

Comment: you mean `math.cos`?

Comment: First Google hit for *"python math cos"*: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.cos *"Any and all feedback would be useful ^_^"* - learn to search! Also note that the IDE you're using doesn't generally affect the modules available to you.

Answer (score 2):

Python's [`math`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module:

A simple Google search would have helped.